# ambiguity in Assignment in FullPivHouseholder::inverse() call for 3.3.rc1

Tags: eigen

I'm running into a problem with ambiguity with an Assignment partial specialization inside the inverse method of the full-pivot Householder decomposition of a dense matrix in the first release candidate for 3.3, 3.3.rc1. Here's a minimal example that produces the error we're getting compiling the Stan math library:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
  using Eigen::MatrixXd;
  MatrixXd m(2, 2);
  m << 1, 0, 0, 1;
  Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<MatrixXd> hh
    = m.fullPivHouseholderQr();
  MatrixXd m_inv_transpose = hh.inverse();
}
```

Are we not using FullPivHouseholderQR the right way?

Here's the error I get using clang++ on Mac OS X (Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)):

```
temp2$ clang++ -isystem ~/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1 fph.cpp

In file included from fph.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/carp/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from /Users/carp/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1/Eigen/Core:389:
/Users/carp/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:813:3: error: ambiguous partial specializations
      of 'Assignment, Eigen::Inverse > >, Eigen::internal::assign_op, Eigen::internal::Dense2Dense, void>'
  Assignment::run(actualDst, src, func);
  ^
/Users/carp/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:721:17: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias,
      Eigen::Inverse > >, Eigen::internal::assign_op
      >' requested here
      internal::call_assignment_no_alias(this->derived(), other.derived(), internal::assign_op());
                ^
/Users/carp/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:531:7: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase
      >::_set_noalias > > >' requested here
      _set_noalias(other);
      ^
/Users/carp/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:379:9: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase
      >::PlainObjectBase > > >' requested here
      : Base(other.derived())
        ^
fph.cpp:9:30: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::Matrix::Matrix > > >' requested here
  MatrixXd m_inv_transpose = hh.inverse();
                             ^
/Users/carp/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:851:8: note: partial specialization matches
      [with DstXprType = Eigen::Matrix, SrcXprType =
      Eigen::Inverse > >, Functor =
      Eigen::internal::assign_op, Weak = void]
struct Assignment
       ^
/Users/carp/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1/Eigen/src/LU/InverseImpl.h:290:8: note: partial specialization matches [with
      DstXprType = Eigen::Matrix, XprType = Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR >]
struct Assignment, internal::assign_op, Dense2Dense>
       ^
/Users/carp/cmdstan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.rc1/Eigen/src/QR/FullPivHouseholderQR.h:579:8: note: partial specialization matches
      [with DstXprType = Eigen::Matrix, MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix, Scalar = double]
struct Assignment >, internal::assign_op, Dense2Dense>
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: [Fixed](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/706501075607/).

Comment: Thanks.  Even better than an answer!